# Is there a way to set DeltaBackoff for RetryExponential policy in .NET Core ServiceBus client?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

It seems that .NET Standard Azure ServiceBus client [library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) doesn't have exposed possibility to set `DeltaBackoff` parameter. It was possible before, based on documentation it should be still possible. I see there is an internal [constructor](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/src/RetryExponential.cs#L26) which is chained to the public one and value for `DeltaBackoff` is passed from `Constants.DefaultRetryDeltaBackoff` (3 seconds).

Is there a valid reason to not expose that anymore? Also, is there a way to achieve exponential retries using `SubscriptionClient` with 2/4/8 minutes delay without setting `DeltaBackoff`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find the other way than using reflection to instantiate `RetryExponential` via its internal constructor:

```
var internalCtor = typeof(RetryExponential)
    .GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Single();

var instance = (RetryExponential)internalCtor.Invoke(
    new object[] { TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(8), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), 3 }
    );

Console.WriteLine(instance.DeltaBackoff); // 00:02:00
```

Here is the issue on the [repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/8785), if someone wants to track it.